# How to change Nginx proxy response body

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy

How can I set the proxy response body?

Just like [proxy_set_body](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_body), but setting the *response* body, not the request body.